# Standalone Indicator inTradingview

Tags: currency, moving-average, indicator, pine-script

I have written this strategy with 3 MA (18ema, 50ema and 200sma)... 
On my 15min chart (which I use for trading), if 18ema is below 50ema and 50ema is below 200sma and also 18ema MUST be below 50ema and 50ema MUST be below 200sma, then I plot red diamond on top of the chart like so:
[Signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoWmA.jpg)

This would be to look for short entry. The opposite would be for long... So far so good. What I am trying to do is instead of flipping through the chart to look for these setups, is there a way to do something like this instead:
[standalone indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KPEw.jpg)

if 18ema is below 50ema and 50ema is below 200sma show Red diamond in M15 box just like above picture
if 18ema is below 50ema and 50ema is below 200sma show Red diamond in 1HR box just like above picture for currency pair AUDUSD... repeat the same for x amount of currency... again, just like the picture above. The bottom line is to have one place to look for the setup instead of flipping through the charts.

Here is the code that I have which I am currently using as shown on the very first picture above:

```
//@version=3
study(title="Inpulse Pullback 15", overlay=true)

s18ema = ema(close, 18)     //slower 18EMA
s50ema = ema(close, 50)     //medium 50EMA
s200sma = sma(close, 200)   //slowest 200SMA
price = open[1]

s2 = security(tickerid, "60", s18ema) // 60 Minutes
s3 = security(tickerid, "60", s50ema) // 60 Minutes
s4 = security(tickerid, "60", s200sma) // 60 Minutes

plot(s18ema, title="EMA 18", color = aqua, linewidth = 1, transp=0)
plot(s50ema, title="EMA 50", color = orange, linewidth = 2, transp=0)
plot(s200sma, title="SMA 200", color = blue, linewidth = 2, transp=0)


longCondSig = (s18ema > s50ema) and (s50ema > s200sma) and (s2 > s3) and (s3 > s4)
shortCondSig = (s18ema < s50ema) and (s50ema < s200sma) and (s2 < s3) and (s3 < s4)


plotshape(series=longCondSig, title="Long", style=shape.diamond, location=location.top, color=#29ee0b, transp=0, size=size.small)
plotshape(series=shortCondSig, title="Short", style=shape.diamond, location=location.top, color=red, transp=0, size=size.small)

longEntry = longCondSig ==1
shortEntry = shortCondSig ==1
alertcondition(longEntry, "le", "le")
alertcondition(shortEntry, "se", "se")
```

Comment: Can you use a different website to upload your images?

Comment: you can't see the pictures here? Not sure where else to post them